# How to find $\nabla u\cdot \nu|_{B(0,1)} $ where $u$ is solution of given conductivity equation?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I have encountered the following problem.

Let $\chi:=\chi_{B(0,1/2)}$ be characteristics function i.e it take $1$ if $x\in B(0,1/2)$ otherwise $0$.

$\nabla\cdot ((1+\chi_{B(0,1/2)})\nabla u )=0 $ in $B(0,1)$ with $u(1,\theta)=f(\theta)$.

I wanted to find $(\nabla u\cdot \nu)|_{B(0,1)} $ from above data where $\nu$ is outer unit normal on disc.  I know the given problem is elliptic. But I do not know any technique to tackle that problem. Please suggest some technique to tackle that problem.

Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.